# Build Multi Page Apps in Vite in separate directories

Tags: svelte, vite

Vite provides the option to build multi-page using rollupOptions in vite.config.js: https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app. However, all the output assets are bunched together in a single output directory. Is there a way to generate each page/app in a separate directory?

Something similar to this?

```
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    // Is something like this possible?
    rollupOptions: [
        {
            input: "src/page1.html",
            output: { file: "dist/page1/page1.js", format: 'es' },
        },
        {
            input: "src/page2.html",
            output: { file: "dist/page2/page2.js", format: 'es' },
        },
    ],
  },
})
```

Use case: The backend handles routing, Svelte is used to generate a static frontend page for each path.

Relevant Github issue: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/817

Comment: I don't see how the assets being in the same directory is an issue

Comment: In our case, we want separate directories because we build 4 separate apps as a mono repo off the same vite config with multiple inputs.  We don't want to run the vite build 4 times, it's so much slower to do that and makes our PR Validation Pipeline and Build Pipelines take way longer than we want them to.   Especially on a large team with 15+ Pr's a day.  I really dislike smacking the output on the disk and then setting up reverse proxies so everything loads the way we want it to.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Thanks